# How to rescale image node?

Tags: graphviz

Without using HTML, what is a straightforward way to resize external images used in a GraphViz document? 
For example, with the following:

```
somenode [size=1 image="littleperson.png", label=""];
```

How can the image be made smaller? [Preferably without HTML, using HTML if it's most straightforward/unavoidable.]

I'm not having much luck with HTML:

```
somenode [label=<<IMG SRC="littleperson.png" />>];
```

Throws back an error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can make the external images smaller several ways.

- Without HTML, Using imagescale attribute and / or fixedsize attribute, along with the `width` and `height` attributes of the node.

  `somenode [width=50 height=50 fixedsize=true image="littleperson.png", label=""];`
- With HTML (img HTML tag takes the scale attribute which has same parameters as imagescale), attributes for fixedsize and height and width are of the td which contains the image tag.

  `somenode [label=< <table><tr><td fixedsize="true" width="50" height="50"><img src="littleperson.png" /></td></tr></table>  >];`
- Resize the image in a external program and load it

  `somenode [image="littleperson_resized.png", label=""];`

**Further documentation / References**

- [How to display an image in a Node](https://web.archive.org/web/20200128174538/http://graphviz.996277.n3.nabble.com/How-to-display-an-image-in-a-NODE-td3032.html)
- [How to set width and height of image displayed in a Node](https://web.archive.org/web/20190814070420/http://graphviz.996277.n3.nabble.com/how-to-set-width-amp-height-of-image-displayed-in-a-node-td3694.html)
- [Graphviz Shapes Documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html)
- [Graphviz Attribute Documentation](http://www.graphviz.org/content/attrs)

Comment: The first option does not work - when compiling (it's gigantic) with neato e.g. "neato -Tpng -Kdot sample.dot -o sample.png"